# BXSlider with multiple instances and custom controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, bxslider

i have currently implemented bxslider on a site i am working on. The page in question has 3 sliders on it with custom next and previous controls.

I've setup the bxslider using a class instead of an id.

```
$('.carousel').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 3,
  slideWidth: 139,
  slideMargin: 30,
  pager: false,
  nextSelector: '.carousel-next',
  prevSelector: '.carousel-prev',
  nextText: 'Onward →',
  prevText: '← Go back' 
});
```

The sliders load ok apart from there are 3 sets of controls on each slider now - is there anyway to turn the above into some sort of loop and have each slider work with their own independent next and previous buttons?

```
<div class="carousel-container">
<ul class="carousel">
<li><img src="images/beer.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/beer.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/beer.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/beer.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/beer.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/beer.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/beer.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/beer.jpg" /></li>
</ul>       

<a class="carousel-prev"></a>
<a class="carousel-next"></a>                           
</div><!-- carousel-container -->
```

Slider screenshot in the below link.

[Slider Screenshot HERE](http://i59.tinypic.com/hry6ar.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I have this problem and solved with this:

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        nextSelector: '#slider-next',
        prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
        controls: true,
        pager: false,
        nextText: '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/TZDsPC0.png" height="25" width="25"/>',
        prevText: '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/AKjTWvT.png" height="25" width="25"/>'
    });
});`

[Bxslider Custom Control](http://jsfiddle.net/qLSGe/1/)